# mysql: select using like operator and order the result by column name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
```

Edit: sorry missed $. syntax errors - ok

```
$qry="SELECT * 
      FROM `tbl_postad` 
      WHERE category LIKE '% $car %'
        OR title LIKE '% $car %' 
        OR text LIKE '% $car %'";
```

but I want the output to list the rows by category first and then title and then description. 
Is there any without using union
Thanks in advance.

Example:

```
 id category title description   
  1    car 
  2    car
  3            car
  4            car
  5            car
  6                    car


?>
```

Comment: You are missing an `AND` in that query, and that is all people are going to see to start with. Edit your question to fix that

Comment: thanks riggs i edited it

Comment: Based on your data, I assume you intend `OR`, rather than `AND`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN category LIKE '% $car %' THEN 0
              WHEN title LIKE '% $car %' THEN 1
              WHEN description LIKE '% $car %' THEN 2
         END
```

Comment: bro actually I am using a like operator don't know exact string

Comment: I don't understand, you can use the same string variable you use for your `like` for your `order by`, right? On second thought, I think I may understand what you meant, in that case use `like` in the `order by` as well

Comment: yeah bro actually I am using a variable in for like operator I missed the $ sign

Answer (score 2):

You can try like below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tbl_postad` 
WHERE category LIKE '%car%' OR title LIKE '%car%' OR description LIKE '%car%'
ORDER BY (category LIKE '%car%') DESC,
     (title LIKE '%car%') DESC,
     (description LIKE '%car%') DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same think using `like` as =`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tbl_postad` 
WHERE category LIKE '% car %' OR title LIKE '% car %' OR text LIKE '% car %'
ORDER BY (category LIKE '% car %') DESC,
         (title LIKE '% car %') DESC,
         (text LIKE '% car %') DESC;
```

Based on your sample data, I assume you intend `OR` rather than `AND`.